# ScheduledTask output redirection

Tags: streams, message-coding

When a function is run repeatedly within a ScheduledTask its output is sent to Messages Window. When two or more ScheduledTasks are running their outputs are mixed in the Messages Window and this is highly undesirable for me. 
I can’t find how to redirect the outputs to separate notebooks or windows.  Does anybody know how to do it? Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Is `NotebookWrite` a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't. Any Print[] command from any ScheduledTask running in any kernel goes to Messages Window :(

Comment: Perhaps write the output from each task to its own log file.